# Clipping lines not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip

Trying to clip a line layer with another renders an empty shapefile. I've looked through older threads and have made sure that the CRS is the same (they do align) and that I've converted multipart files to singlepart ones and use these for clipping.  Have tried with numerous line layers from different datasets. Still getting nothing but an empty shapefile.

Using QGIS 2.10 (tried with the new 2.12 as well) in Windows 7.

Comment: What do you expect from clipping a line with another line? A line may *intersect* another line, then the lines can be splitted, or nodes may be inserted at the crossings. This operation would be *Intersection*, not *Clip*. Clipping requires the clipper to be of polygon shape. This can be the extent of a line layer, the convex or concave hull around all lines of the *clip* layer. In these cases lines overlaying such a polygon geometry would be retained, while the parts outside would be deleted.